# What is the lowest power consume way to print over bluetooth on Android?

Tags: android, printing, bluetooth

I'm developing an app that requires to print over Bluetooth to a Bixolon thermal printer.I have already got it, so if you need help to print over Bluetooth, I would be happy to help you.

The Dilemma:  The final user for this app will print an invoice every 3-5 minutes for a period of 4-5 hours daily so I need the lowest power consume possible.

I'm stocked in this two possible ways:

- Connect to the printer every time the user will need to used it. It will take around 1.5-2 seconds to print having the BT id saved on the database.
- Connect to the device just one time and leave the connection open at all time.

What is the best way?

I appreciate your help thank you! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you should not worry so much about the power consumption, because Bluetooth was design to be a low power replacement for classic cables. But you should read this article: [Bluetooth and power consumption: issues and answers](http://mobiledevdesign.com/hardware_news/radio_bluetooth_power_consumption/), I think it's relevant for your case.

The first approach you mention I think it is not good, because it will be first of all frustrating for the user, to wait all the time to re-authenticate. Second it will consume more energy because you have the reconnection overhead.

The second approach is more economic.